# Why does rsync always marks all folders as changed?

Tags: rsync

I'm on macOS Ventura and use rsync 3.2.7 to synchronize files between a NAS and a external hard drive.

When I run

```
rsync -avP --delete /Volumes/NAS/photos /Volumes/EXTERNAL_DRIVE
```

rsync marks all folders and subfolders as changed although they didn't change. Only for files it works as intended. When I run the same command again, again all folders and subfolders are detected as changed.

I compare the ls output:

```
drwxrwxrwx  1 user  staff  131072 24 Apr 16:53 MyAlbum42      <-- On NAS
drwx------  1 user  staff   16384 24 Apr 16:53 MyAlbum42      <-- On EXTERNAL_DRIVE
```

It seems the `-a` flag is ignored as it also consists of `-p` (Preserve permissions).

Output of `mount | grep -F /Volumes`:

```
/dev/disk1s1 on /System/Volumes/NAS (apfs, local, journaled, nobrowse)
/dev/disk2s1 on /Volumes/EXTERNAL_DRIVE (exfat, local, nodev, nosuid, noowners)
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Is the NAS a Synology unit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exFAT filesystem you're using on the external disk is not capable of matching the APFS file permissions you have on you NAS disk.

You can either reformat the external disk or live with the situation. If you reformat the disk as APFS you will lose all its existing data but going forwards you'll have total local compatibility. You'll lose interoperability with, say, Windows systems because they can't read APFS filesystems but that may not be an issue for you.